# Ruby hash to json with JSON.parse error

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I'm trying to do a json to hash, but I give this

```
JSON.parse({"tag":"DownloadRequest","hash":"c8\u0006ùM]ÁaSßwÃ9\u0007Ãò\u0013Â4lÊ·|j\\ëç","part_number":0})
TypeError: exception class/object expected
```

How I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

What you're currently passing to [JSON#parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) isn't a valid Ruby [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html) object; it's just raw JSON. JSON#parse expects a string containing valid JSON instead. Everything works fine if you wrap your JSON inside a string like so:

```
require 'json'
str = '{"tag":"DownloadRequest","hash":"c8\u0006ùM]ÁaSßwÃ9\u0007Ãò\u0013Â4lÊ·|j\\ëç","part_number":0}'
JSON.parse str
```

It now returns:

> {"tag"=>"DownloadRequest",
>    "hash"=>"c8\u0006ùM]ÁaSßwÃ9\aÃò\u0013Â4lÊ·|jëç",
>    "part_number"=>0}